# laravel register custom validator

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

for laravel 5 i want to create and define custom validator, but i can't find whitch file and folder i must be register that, i can not find that in laravel documents, for example after create `Extension\Validation` folders into `app` folder, i'm create this class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Extension\Validation;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
class CustomValidator extends Validator {

    public function validateNationalCode ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}$/', $value)) {
            return false;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            if (preg_match('/^' . $i . '{10}$/', $value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for ($i = 0, $sum = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
            $sum += ((10 - $i) * intval(substr($value, $i, 1)));
        }
        $ret = $sum % 11;
        $parity = intval(substr($value, 9, 1));

        if (($ret < 2 && $ret == $parity) || ($ret >= 2 && $ret == 11 - $parity)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

now i must be use below code to register that :

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

**Laravel Document:**

> Registering A Custom Validator Resolver
>   Next, you need to register your custom Validator extension:

**which file i must be add or append?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to /app/providers/appServiceProviders.php then use validator on your class

```
use Validator;
```

then write your custom validation in boot method,like this

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('alpha_dash_spaces', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        return (bool) preg_match( "/^[A-Za-z\s-_]+$/", $value );
    });
}
```

Then go /resources/land/en/validator.php and write your custom validation messages like this

```
'alpha_num_spaces'     => 'The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, and spaces.',
```

Comment: i get this error: `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'App\Providers\Validator' not found`

Comment: @mahdipishguy i edited code to use validator class,please try again